# How to globally rotate the screen to a specified orientation (even with private api) in jailbroken iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, tweak

My tweak is running inside `SpringBoard`, in which I need it be able to rotate the whole screen to a specified orientation and keep there.I've searched much with Google but got nothing, most of them are just talking about how to get the orientation changed notification.How can I set the orientation by force, could anyone help?I'll very appreciate it.

This code looks fit but doesn't work in my testing:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 7

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

for iOS 8

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Write above code in an event on which you want to rotate your screen.

And make sure the app supports orientation that you want.

To enable multiple orientation go in the app targets and check mark orientation like below [image]

Comment: Above code works perfect to me If you write the reason of minus marking than it will be helpful to me to know where i got it wrong

Comment: Here is a project with code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KnvB_2930adnVDZnBQVWRYRFE/view?usp=sharing